# “Object doesn't support this property or method”

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have searched google for a long time before asking this question, but no luck.

I am trying to open a pop up using jquery, but I am unable to do it. I have included jquery-v.v.v.js and jquery-ui.custom.js in my jsp as follows.

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
            src="../js/common/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
             src="../js/common/jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
```

And in the jsp file I have form. Upon submitting the form, it calls a service(from struts 1.x action class) and returns some data which I have to show in the pop up. This is the code I am using to do this work.

```
    function ValidateAddresspopup(){
      var url ='<%= request.getContextPath()%>'+"/uspsValidation.do";
      $.post(url, {homeaddress2:document.forms[0].streetCurr.value,homecity:document.forms[0].cityCurr.value, homezip5:document.forms[0].currZip5.value, homestate:document.forms[0].statecurr.value,mailaddress2:document.forms[0].streetChange.value,mailcity:document.forms[0].cityChange.value,mailzip5:document.forms[0].zip5Change.value,mailstate:document.forms[0].statechange.value,medicaidid:document.forms[0].medicaidid.value}, function(data) {

              alert("data"+data.trim());

             registerModalDialog("msAddrModal");
             openViewDialog("msAddrModal");

             //some code to split the data received and set in the popup fields. });
```

I have returned the data from the action class as a string and I can see the data in the alert. The registerModalDialog() and openViewDialog() functions are as follows.

```
    function registerModalDialog(dialogId){
      $('#'+dialogId).dialog({
      autoOpen : false,
      modal : true,
      dialogClass : 'web_dialog',
      width : 'auto',
      height : 'auto',
      draggable : false
}).parent().draggable();}

    function openViewDialog(divId)
    {
     $('#'+divId).dialog("open");
     $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
     $(".ui-dialog-content").css("padding", 0);
     $(".ui-dialog").css("overflow", "hidden"); }
```

The argument passed to both the functions is the id of the div I want to show in the pop up.
Now I am getting the error "“Object doesn't support this property or method”. and it is pointing the line

```
$('#'+dialogId).dialog(
```

of registerModalDialog() function.
We are using struts1.x and our project is deployed in websphere6.5.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Open console and type $.fn.dialog, or $.dialog. If the plugin is there you will see it print out the function. If it's not it means it's not loaded or it was requested before being included (but will aid you to diagnose what is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui.custom.js may not contain a widget dialog. Are you sure he was selected on the page http://jqueryui.com/download/ when you receive jquery-ui.custom.js?

Try execute

```
$().dialog()
```

on your page with

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
        src="../js/common/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"
         src="../js/common/jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
```

Any errors?

Comment: It works properly in Tomcat. I'm getting the problem only when I deploy my app in Websphere 6.5. Any help is appreciated.